# Unable to build android in IONIC 4 on MAC : ionic cordova build android

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

Unable to create build for android from Ionic 4 solution.

```
Command: ionic cordova build android 

Error:
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
```

Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio

I have android studio installed. I manually downloaded the gradle and kept in the path as well.
I have all the environment variables present. Still i have the same error message as shown above.

**ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES**

```
COMMAND: open  ~/.bash_profile

export GRADLE_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/gradle/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Java/Home
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
```

I tried the below link in ionic forum and many other but of no help:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cannot-build-android-apk-ionic-4/184154

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What does running `gradle -v` return?

Comment: Java path was incorrect as there were many versions installed.Now its working fine after correcting the JAVA_HOME environment variable. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME environment variable was incorrect due to multiple versions installed on my machine. I pointed it to the latest version and the issue is resolved.